# How to override locate_template function?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to remap Wordpress' template files to a subdirectory in my theme (something like `views` folder). I've tried some hooks I found on Wordpress documentation, but nothing worked as expected.

Analysing core function that "includes" theme's template files, I've found the `locate_template` function on *wp-includes/template.php* file. I want to override that function to reach what I want.

So, the original function body is:

```
function locate_template( $template_names, $load = false, $require_once = true, $args = array() ) {
    $located = '';
    foreach ( (array) $template_names as $template_name ) {
        if ( ! $template_name ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $load && '' !== $located ) {
        load_template( $located, $require_once, $args );
    }

    return $located;
}
```

And the override is just appending an `views/` to the path that Wordpress searches for template files, like this:

```
function locate_template( $template_names, $load = false, $require_once = true, $args = array() ) {
    $located = '';
    foreach ( (array) $template_names as $template_name ) {
        if ( ! $template_name ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/views/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = STYLESHEETPATH . '/views/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/views/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = TEMPLATEPATH . '/views/' . $template_name;
            break;
        } elseif ( file_exists( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name ) ) {
            $located = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/' . $template_name;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $load && '' !== $located ) {
        load_template( $located, $require_once, $args );
    }

    return $located;
}
```

I know that modifying core functions is a (BIG) mistake, so what I want is to override this function from my theme's *functions.php* file. I think I just need to re-declare this function on some initialization hook, but I can't find what hook to use (and if this is the correct way to do this).

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

"I'm trying to remap Wordpress' template files to a subdirectory in my theme"

Why? Use a child theme. Anything else would be brittle and error prone.

Consider using an htaccess file for the remap.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new theme structure inspired on MVC format. That's the reason why I'm trying to map template files (`404.php`, `single.php`, `page.php`, `home.php` etc) into an *views/* subfolder in my theme. I've looked on Sage (roots.io/sage) and it does something like that (template files are in *resources/views/*), but using Blade and a "cache" system that I dont want. So I'm searching a way to do that from scratch.